# strange behaviour of assigning char array to single char

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
// example: class constructor
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test{
public:
    char* getColor(){
        return color;
    }
private:
    char color[5] = "Blau";
};

int main () {
    Test s;
    char *myChar = s.getColor();
    std::cout << myChar;
    return 0;
};
```

I don't really understand how this actually returns "Blau" instead of just B or something else.

What I'm doing is assigning the starting pointer if a char array to a single char pointer.

I'd really like to understand why this happens like this. Maybe it's because of std::cout getting all values of that type? So instead of "B" it says "Blau"

Comment: `myChar` is not a single char, it is a pointer to a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between a pointer to a single object and a pointer to the first element of an array. It's up to the programmer to know how it should be interpreted; or to use friendlier types like `std::string`.

When you stream a `char*` with `<<`, it assumes that it's the pointer to the first element of a zero-terminated C-style string, and prints all the characters it finds, starting from that one, until it finds one with a zero value.

Comment: How would I go about assigning a char[] I get from a function to another char[] with the same size? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Code0: Not directly. You can copy, but you must do so manually, for example with a library function, like `std::copy` `std::memcpy` `std::strcpy` ... C and C++ arrays are quite second-class.

Comment: @Code0: Arrays aren't assignable; they're rather quirky types dating back to prehistoric times. Use `std::string` if you want a friendly string type that's easy to copy and compare.

Answer (score 1):

`myChar` is not a single `char` but a pointer to such (and you can always do pointer-arithmetic / indexing instead of straight dereferencing).

And `operator<<` has an overload for `ostream&`+`char*`, to output it as a pointer to a 0-terminated string.

So, not really any surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Array in c++ is the const pointer to first element of data block. Therefore your color variable is the pointer.